# Typescript: Argument of type 'RegExpMatchArray' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript1.8, typescript-typings

I have the following expression:

```
import { persistState } from 'redux-devtools';

const enhancer = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk, router, logger),
  DevTools.instrument(),
  persistState(
    window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/)
  )
);
```

I get a swiggly on the argument to match function with the following error

> Argument of type 'RegExpMatchArray' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'string'. Matches a string with a regular expression, and returns
>   an array containing the results of that search. (method)
>   String.match(regexp: RegExp): RegExpMatchArray (+1 overload)

The peek definition in VSCode shows:

```
match(regexp: string): RegExpMatchArray;
/**
  * Matches a string with a regular expression, and returns an array containing the results of that search.
  * @param regexp A regular expression object that contains the regular expression pattern and applicable flags.
  */
match(regexp: RegExp): RegExpMatchArray;

/**
  * Replaces text in a string, using a regular expression or search string.
  * @param searchValue A string that represents the regular expression.
  * @param replaceValue A string containing the text to replace for every successful match of searchValue in this string.
  */
```

As I see it, the argument is of type RegExp and so is the parameter in the definition. Then why the error?

Comment: what are you doing with the result of the match?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@NitzanTomer is right. It's not the match functions parameter that has a type mismatch. You certainly try to store the return value of the match function in a string typed variable / return it from a `:string` function / pass it as a `string` parameter.

Comment: I think it was an issue with VSCode intellisense. The swiggly was only on the argument to match while the entire statement `window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/)` should have the swiggly.

Restarting VSCode fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @KushagraSharma, restarting vscode was indeed my solution too. Do you have any idea if this bug has been reported?

Comment: @MaximeBernard I don't know if the issue has been reported.