# Having issues with this.contacts.push(contact); & if(data.n==1)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having issues with this two errors:

**Error: src/app/contact/contact.component.ts:34:28 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Task[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Contact'.

Type 'Task[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Contact':
first_name, last_name, phone
34         this.contacts.push(contact); 

~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/contact/contact.component.ts:49:17 - error TS2339: Property 'n' does not exist on type 'Task[]'.
49         if(data.n==1)**

```
import { ContactService } from './../contact.service';
import { Contact } from '../contact';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
  providers:[ContactService]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
  contacts!:Contact[];
  contact!: Contact;
  first_name!: string; //! = Ensures Typescript you're certain value is not null/undefined
  last_name!: string;
  phone!:string;

  //Injects service
  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }

  addContact()
  {
    const newContact = 
    {
      first_name : this.first_name,
      last_name : this.last_name,
      phone : this.phone  

    }
    this.contactService.addContacts(newContact)
    .subscribe(contact =>
      {
        this.contacts.push(contact);
        this.contactService.getContacts()
        .subscribe(contacts => this.contacts = contacts);
      }); 

  }


  deleteContact(id:any)
  {
    
    var contacts = this.contacts;
    this.contactService.deleteContacts(id)
    .subscribe(data => 
      {
        if(data.n==1)
        {
          for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
          {
            if(contacts[i]._id ==id)
            {
              contacts.splice(i,1);
            }

          }
        }
      }
      );
  }


  ngOnInit() 
  {
    //Initialize when browser is loaded
    this.contactService.getContacts()
    .subscribe(contacts => this.contacts = contacts);
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm using Visual studio code. i have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738799/argument-of-type-x-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-x/34738923 for error TS 2345 and error TS2339: Property 'n' does not exist on type 'Task[]'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y. It doesnt't fit my context

Comment: I'm using Angular.cli version 12.2.0